# running Matlab on background BASH

Tags: bash, matlab, background

I'm trying to run a script of matlab in BASH in the background the following way:

```
echo "matlab -nojvm -r p=setpath(/mydirectory/);addpath(p);myscript;exit" |sh &
```

the error I get is:

```
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token '('
sh: line 1: 'matlab -nojvm -r p=setpath(/mydirectory/);addpath(p);myscript;exit'
```

I am running it in a loop so this operation needs to be done several times

1. Is the error relates to the pipeline? whenever I run the matlab on the bg it is suspended and for simple commands or uploading the gui the pipeline worked well.
2. is there away to set matlab's path from the BASH?
3. I try to run the Matlab without the GUI or anything "poping up", when I run with -nodesktop -nojvm it does not open the3 GUI but still enters the matlab and waits in the command line, is there another synthax I can use to make nothing appear on screen?

could use your help, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution thanks to the next website of the OHIO state Uni

```
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < file.m &> file.out &
```

it works without any bypassing route

for further explanation go to

http://www.stat.osu.edu/computer-support/programming/background-jobs

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
echo 'matlab -nojvm -r "p=setpath(/mydirectory/);addpath(p);myscript;exit"' |sh &
```

The outer single quotes protect the inner double quotes so `sh` doesn't see the parentheses.

Is there any reason you can't just:

```
matlab -nojvm -r "p=setpath(/mydirectory/);addpath(p);myscript;exit" &
```

or perhaps:

```
matlab -nojvm -r "p=setpath(/mydirectory/);addpath(p);myscript;exit" </dev/null &
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, whenever I put the command without the pipeline it is automatically suspended, I don't really know how to work  it out. thanks for the help

Comment: @jarhead: try the last example with the redirection.

Comment: It seems to work, but I still need to run some tests to know for sure, thank u. BTW what is the difference and why one is better than the other?

Comment: Using the redirection avoids spawning a subshell, so there's one less process. And the quoting is simplified. Does it also fix point 3 in your question?

Comment: Hi dennis, when I run the command with the redirection,  the command is done just after it is executed (this script needs to run at least an hour). now when I run it I don't get anything, and when I do ps or top there is no proccess,any ideas?

Comment: @jarhead: Sorry, no more ideas. Does the version piped into `sh` work with the extra quoting?